# Parole che descrivono persone che godono della sofferenza degli altri

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice

Volevo sapere quali parole possono essere usate in italiano per descrivere persone che godono della sofferenza degli altri.

Comment: Nella domanda c'è un refuso: cell (del - immagino, oppure volevi usare un'altra preposizione?).

Answer (score 4):

Una tale persona è *sadica*. Deriva dal francese *sadisme*, termine coniato nel 1869 in ambito psichiatrico, dal nome del marchese de Sade, scrittore di opere caratterizzate da un erotismo crudele. Nasce dunque con una connotazione sessuale, ma il suo significato si è esteso in generale al trarre piacere dal causare dolore, fisico o psicologico, agli altri.

È interessante che in italiano (così come in francese e in inglese, e presumo nelle altre lingue) non vi siano sinonimi  né di *sadismo* né del contrapposto [*masochismo*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/masochismo/). Il termine [*algolagnia*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/algolagnia/) ingloba entrambi i concetti.

Comment: Tutto questo è giusto e vero, ma sospetto che l'OP avesse in mente più qualcosa di corrispondente alla *Schadenfreude*.

Comment: @DaG: Vero, possibile. La parola "soffrire" mi aveva fatto pensare al dolore fisico, aspettiamo chiarimenti.

Comment: @JackMaddington: Potresti chiarire se la risposta è soddisfacente o DaG ha ragione?

Answer (score 2):

Prendendo spunto dal commento di DaG rispetto alla [*Schadenfreude*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude), su Wikipedia si può leggere:

> Il termine deriva da Schaden ("danno") e Freude ("gioia"). In tedesco
>   il termine ha sempre una connotazione negativa. Esiste una distinzione
>   tra la "Schadenfreude segreta" (un sentimento privato) e la
>   "Schadenfreude aperta" (Hohn).
>
> Viene talvolta usato come prestito linguistico in molte lingue,
>   compreso l'italiano, sebbene sia attestato il termine analogo
>   ***aticofilia*** (dal greco ἀτυχής atychḗs "sfortunato" e φιλία philía
>   "amore, passione"). Benché tale termine tradisca in parte la
>   "popolarità" della parola tedesca, come giustamente afferma la
>   traduttrice Marina Taffetani, il termine si presta ad un utilizzo
>   di tipo scientifico: in tale contesto, ad esempio, la psicologa e
>   psicoterapeuta Grazia Aloi sottolinea la caratteristica che accomuna
>   Schadenfreude e sadismo, quella di essere "filie", cioè “piaceri,
>   passioni, amori per...” Il concetto di Schadenfreude potrebbe anche
>   venire parafrasato come "compiacimento malevolo" verso il prossimo,
>   derivante, secondo la psicologa, dalla "considerazione di scarsissimo
>   valore di Sé che si riflette nella consolazione (molto spesso errata)
>   che anche il Sé degli altri sia scarso e non degno." La questione
>   dell'aticofilia è "sì anche di interesse clinico ma - fin qui - ancora
>   nell'ordine della morale; tant'è che nessuno può essere punito o
>   curato per ciò" sebbene possa "arrivare alla cattiveria più efferata".

In questo passaggio in effetti Schadenfreude e sadismo sembrano essere considerati due concetti differenti accomunati dalla "filia".

Da notare il termine aticofilia, citato nell'opera ***Il labirinto di Osiride*** di Paul Sussman, tradotto da Gaetano Luigi Staffilano.

> «Non sono mai stato per il governo della plebaglia ma non si può fare
>   a meno di provare una qualche forma di aticofilia, una Schadenfreude,
>   quando si vede che i bastardi assaggiano un po' della loro stessa
>   medicina.» (Paul Sussman, Il labirinto di Osiride, Milano, Mondadori,
>   2013.)

In questo [post nel blog della traduttrice Marina Taffetani](https://marinataffetani.wordpress.com/category/parole/) circa la Schadenfreude, oltre al termine aticofilia viene menzionato anche ***faulofilia***, dal greco φαῦλος (fâulos) significa «cattivo» (e sostantivato, τὸ φαῦλος «il male»).:

> Per comprendere questa bellissima e intraducibile parola tedesca, ci
>   viene in aiuto anche la Wikipedia italiana, che ci dice che la
>   Schadenfreude è il “piacere provocato dalla sfortuna altrui”.
>   Wikipedia propone di tradurlo con aticofilia o faulofilia, che però
>   renderebbero la parola molto aulica, mentre in tedesco è parola di uso
>   comune. Wikipedia riporta anche una lista di parole in altre lingue
>   che hanno lo stesso o simile significato, come il danese e norvegese
>   skadefryd o l’albanese cmirëzi.
>
> Per capirci con un concetto molto semplice, è quel sentimento che
>   qualcuno potrebbe aver provato due sere fa dopo la sconfitta 7-1 del
>   Brasile da parte della Germania ai Mondiali di calcio.